# How can Madara use Susanoo without any eyes?

Tags: naruto

Something that I am confused about Madara's powers.

When Madara used the Rinne Tensei to bring himself back to life, he did not have his eyes, but he had the First Hokage's face embedded into himself.

Even though he did not have his Sharingan or Rinnegan, he was able to use Susanoo.

Is there any explanation for these two anomalies?

[image]

His both eyes were closed at all times, and he had Rinnegan in both his eyes when he was brought back using Edo Tensei. Since his left eye had been destroyed when he was brought back to life using the Rinne Tensei, it is only natural that his right eye too was destroyed.

[image]

Comment: @RJ please check update. It is very clear from the two images that he did not have either rinnegan or sharingan when he was reincarnated using rinne tensi

Comment: Lol RJ just likes to give people a hard time. Also, I suggest you change the title to something like - How can Madara use Susano without any eyes

Comment: @krikara - That's because I don't follow Manga that much. And according to the anime, this is still way beyond comprehension because currently Madara is a re-animated guy, with an indestructible body fully under his control with infinite chakra and Rinnegan in both his eyes. The question became clear only after the images were put, and also, the question as such needs to have a few spoiler blocks. Above everything, I always like to know everything from rock bottom and that is why I preferred the SE community to other forums. :)

Comment: @R.J In response to the spoiler block request, it seems as SE has reached a general consensus not to require them. I'm not sure why, but atm there seems to be no distinction from a question pertaining to manga versus the anime. In the end, the user has to read the titled question, and determine whether or not they want to see the entire post with possible spoilers. In the worst case scenario, the title is a spoiler itself lol.

Comment: Same reason he can take a beating by all tailed beasts at once and not even sweat: it's because Kishimoto is a hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While there isn't an explanation in Naruto for why a person is able to use Susanoo without his MS or Rinnegan, it has been done in the past.

The only logical conclusion is that after someone uses Susanoo, they can use it again without the Mangekyou Sharingan. The manga never explicitly stated that Susanoo required the *usage* of the MS. Rather it stated that Susanoo is the third technique MS users obtain after Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu.

When incorporating Japanese Mythology into the equation, we can reason that Susanoo does not require any eye techniques (and the below picture was not an accident). This is taken directly from the [Susanoo Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susanoo):

*All three were born from Izanagi, when he washed his face clean of the pollutants of Yomi, the underworld. Amaterasu was born when Izanagi washed out his left eye, Tsukuyomi was born from the washing of the right eye, and Susanoo from the washing of the nose.*

**Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu comes from the eyes, whereas Susanoo comes from the nose, so one does not need eyes to use Susanoo.**

Source: Ch 577
Note: Itachi doesn't have MS activated. In the Chapter 578, Itachi activates MS when he needs to use it. Thus MS isn't required to use Susanoo. Also, when Madara fights the five Kages and has both Rinnegan, he is also able to use Susanoo.

[image]

Comment: But can this not be a glitch in the plot? Itachi's case can simply be a place where they "forgot" to draw the MS, and Madara's a plot hole?

Comment: @debal It is more reasonable to assume it is not a plothole. I'll edit my post shortly with the explanation.

Comment: With that said, Madara has been shown to be pretty plot immune in the last few chapters, from senjutsu to taking to no visible damage. Although I do truly believe that his usage of Susanoo is not a plothole however.

Comment: A counterargument to this can be seen in Sasukes battle against Kakashi and team 7. While overusing his Mangekyo, Sasukes sharingan looses its light and  his susano completely dissipated. If the mangekyou sharingans are not needed then why does sasuke loose the ability to use susanoo after he goes blind?

Answer (score 2):

It clearly states in the manga and anime that both Mangekyou Sharingan eyes are needed to use Susanoo (where the left and right eye when activated together produce Susanoo). Madara had no eyes at all and used Susanoo (just because he is Madara??). Oh come on that's because they need to cut it out already (stay true to the manga and not this crap).

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer!!!

Comment: Please provide references to manga or external sites to acertain your points.