# How was Madara able to summon Susanoo after he was revived by Rinne Tensei no jutsu?

Tags: naruto

> In Naruto: Shippuden before Madara is able to retrieve one of his Rinnegan after being revived, he fights with the Tailed Beasts by using Susanoo even when he's blind. How is that possible?

Comment: As i Glance over to the Related questions section, I find a possible original  of this question http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/how-can-madara-use-susanoo-without-any-eyes?rq=1