# How did Shisui activate his Susanoo with only one eye?

Tags: naruto

I found this picture on Facebook showing Shisui using Susanoo with only one eye.

[image]

I know that it is impossible to use the Susanoo with one eye.

Is this is real or not? Why was Shisui able to activate Susanoo with just one Mangekyō Sharingan (one eye)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this real or not?

This is a real image, albeit not from the manga nor anime series. Shisui's Susanoo makes its appearance in the video game [*Naruto Shippūden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=26&v=TDOJGUlDjBs&feature=youtu.be). In fact,  Shisui's Susanoo was designed by  Masashi Kishimoto himself. So from that perspective, it is canon.

> Why was Shisui able to activate Susanoo with just one Mangekyō Sharingan (one eye)?

Unfortunately, there is no canonical information regarding this and may have been a simple oversight from the developers of the game.

However, the answer to the question ["How can Madara use Susanoo without any eyes?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6285/20275) may shine some light on the matter.

Comment: It was never stated, that it is required to have both eyes to **use** Susanoo, but one needs to have both eyes to **awaken** it